# Census API returning a rate_sleep() error

Tags: census, tidycensus

I am trying to request all the census tracts for the US using the census API

Here is my API request:

```
cenus_tracts <- get_acs(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = variables,
  geometry = TRUE
)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Fetching data by table type ("B/C", "S", "DP") and combining the result.
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `rate_sleep()`:
! Request failed after 3 attempts.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```